# String to BufferedImage and back to String gives different strings

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have a base64 encoded image string, I converted it to a byte[] and to a bufferedImage, and then back to the string. The two strings I got are different. I got something like `expected:<...1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP[4/x8AAwAB/2+Bq7Y]AAAAASUVORK5CYII=> but was:<...1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP[8/x8AAwMCAO+ip1s]AAAAASUVORK5CYII=>`. I am not sure what caused this. Any help is appreciated!

```
// a 1x1 pixel white png image
String imageString = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP8/x8AAwMCAO+ip1sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(imageString);
String newString = toBase64String(toImage(bytes), "png");
Assert.assertEquals(imageString, newString); // not equal

public static BufferedImage toImage(final byte[] bytes) {
  BufferedImage image = null;

  try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return image;
}

public static String toBase64String(final BufferedImage image, final String formatName) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  try {
    ImageIO.write(image, formatName, baos);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(baos.toByteArray());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return "";
}
```

Comment: Is the output byte encoded image still a 1x1 pixel white png image?

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe Yes it is.

Comment: Fascinating, I haven't read up on it, but I would guess that Base64 encoding is not 1 to 1 then. (i.e. there are multiple valid imageStrings that produce the same image). Probably the encoder you used to create the original string is different than the one Java is using here.

Comment: Just to clarify, base-64 is pretty strictly defined (pad characters notwithstanding), but there are for sure multiple ways to PNG-encode the same image. For example, you can specify different compression levels for PNGs. Whatever Java's PNG writer's default settings are probably differ from the program you used to create the image.

Comment: Thanks @user4851. OP might have to fiddle with the settings of the initial encoder he used to match the default settings used by Java

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe there are also the metadata uniquely set by each PNG encoder. Trying to reproduce exactly the same PNG file back is way beyond the scope of Java's ImageIO, nor is it something someone would normally want.